# Identify tandem frame with no LK99040060

Tags: frames

Looking to identify my tandem frame
It was bought without decals and buyer claimed it to be a Gary Fisher but I want to know for sure before I have it refinished. 
It has eccentric bottom bracket shell and v-brake mounts 
Frame number stamped underneath the shell is LK99040060
Any help gladly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to bicycles stack exchange. Serial number won't help us ID your bike, we need pictures. Here is a link to how to ask a good "ID my bike" question. https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Consider asking the seller for paperwork or documentation.  A sales receipt is often kept  for years, for warranty purposes.

Comment: I've now got some pictures of some logos stamped on the dropouts

Comment: I can't see how to add pictures but the logo is similar to the CND / Peace sign

Comment: I can't find a way to upload a picture but inside the rear dropouts are stamped on a logo similar to the Peace logo. ☢️

Answer (score -2):

IS that the only number listed?  I looked on a bike registry and found nothing, but it may not include tandems, or there is another number stamped on the frame somewhere.  This site: https://bikeindex.org/serials  give pictures and descriptions of different locations for that stamp to be.  But I have not found a registry for tandems or that just says it includes tandems.

I am sorry that I could not help more!  Good luck :)

Comment: There's no database of serial numbers. The fact that you didn't find the serial number in some specific database simply means that it wasn't registered with that site.

Comment: Ok, I just went off what that website said